# How to add a another caption div to a image?

Tags: html

I want to add two captions over a image, after googling around I was able to do coding but it works only for one caption div, when I added second caption div, it disappears..

my code:

```
<style>
.background_image
{
 background:url(1.jpg);  
 width:420px;                    
 height:205px;                   
 border:1px solid #FFFF00;        
 overflow:hidden;                
 }

.text_caption
{
 padding-left:2px;               
 padding-top:0px;                 
 padding-right:2px;              
 padding-bottom:2px;              
 color:#fffff;                  
 font-size:30px;                 
 font-weight:bold;                
 font-family:Trebuchet MS;               
 text-decoration:none;       
 margin-left:5px;                 
 margin-top:140px;                 
 }

.text_caption2
{
 padding-left:4px;                
 padding-top:0px;                 
 padding-right:4px;               
 padding-bottom:0px;             
 color:#000000;                   
 font-size:26px;                 
 font-weight:bold;                
 font-family:Trebuchet MS;               
 text-decoration:none;       
 margin-left:5px;                
 margin-top:150px;                
 }

</style>

<div class="background_image">
<div class="text_caption">Caption 1</div> /* this works */
<div class="text_caption2">Caption 2</div> /* this caption disappears */

</div>
```

Any help with this? whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply to nest the captions into the image, then make the image relative  and captions absolute positioned, like that:

**HTML**

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="text_caption">CAPTION 1</div>
    <div class="text_caption2">CAPTION 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.background {
    position: relative;
    width: 420px;
    height: 205px;
    background: transparent url(http://placehold.it/420x205) top left no-repeat;
    border:1px solid #ffff00;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.text_caption, .text_caption2 {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.text_caption {
    padding: 0 2px 2px;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.text_caption2 {
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:26px;
}
```

Changing the HTML layout in that way, the captions will always follow the related image, and will be positioned always relative to its container (the image).

---

A further enhancement could be to separate image from `.background` class, so that you could define base properties to the image container, and add a class with its own relative properties for every image you want to display (see the code in my fiddle).

---

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/2pzeQ/) the example.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now, now both captions have fixed positions, it wont go here and there now.. thanks for your answer and time, Ragnarokkr. :)

Answer (score 1):

`.text_caption2 { margin-top:150px }` is pushing it off the bottom of the div and the overflow is set to hidden.

Just remove that rule and you should see it.